# Google map SDK on iOS5.1

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using **Google map SDK** in my app. My app supports deployment target of iOS >=5 but the google map SDK included in my app supports iOS >=6. So, when I run my app on iOS5 , the app crashed with the following error :

```
 dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivityViewController
```

I want to run the same app on iOS5 by excluding google map sdk.Does any one know how to include google map sdk in the app only if the device iOS version is >=6?
Do we have any option to make google map framework "**Optional**" or importing the google maps header using **iOS version macros**? If yes, any pointers?

Comment: After the Version 1.5.. iOS 5.1 is no longer supported.. check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Comment: I know it is not supported after version 1.5. But Can I skip adding the framework to the build if iOS >=6?

Comment: try to change the framrework from required to optionls

Comment: Already tried. Did not work.